# duplicate rows occuring when using inner join

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT a.value1,b.value2,a.category 
          FROM sale_villa as a 
          left join sale_land as b on a.area = b.area
          WHERE a.area='$area' 
          AND b.category BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' ";
```

duplicate rows occuring when using inner join..

```
value1  value2
3000000     45000000
4900000     45000000
80000000    45000000
3000000     5000000
4900000     5000000
80000000    5000000
3000000     50000000
4900000     50000000
80000000    50000000
```

actually what i have to get..

```
    value1      value2
    3000000     45000000
    4900000     45000000
    80000000    45000000


 sale_villa
    category

2015-02-01
2015-02-02
2015-02-03

sale_land
category

2015-02-01
2015-02-02
2015-02-03

2015-02-04
```

This is the current [output](http://i60.tinypic.com/2nqqebp.jpg) and db [result](http://i57.tinypic.com/2me7m1z.jpg).

Comment: you selected 3 columns to show but you shared 2 columns.

Comment: category field representing date..

Comment: why are you using left join. try with only join..

Comment: Show your source data including `area` in both tables.

Comment: i used with join, still showing that same error

Comment: can you please share your category column. what's its fetching with left join

Comment: category field represents date.

Comment: Please send more column name here...

Comment: U can send full "sale_villa" table structural...

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/qyeqee.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Try INNER JOIN instead of left join and GROUP BY a.value1